# D3 javascript network: How to parametrize node size with the number of links?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to create a network with d3.js. I have created one as you see below, but I want the node size to depend on the number of links each node has (the more links a node has, the bigger the size of the node, vice versa). Below is the JS I wrote for the nodes.

How do I change the node size with the number of links?

```
var nodes = graph.nodes.slice(),
      links = [],
      bilinks = [];

  graph.links.forEach(function(link) {
    var s = nodes[link.source],
        t = nodes[link.target],
        i = {}; // intermediate node
    nodes.push(i);
    links.push({source: s, target: i}, {source: i, target: t});
    bilinks.push([s, i, t]);
  });

var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 3)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
```

[image]

Comment: And what is the problem? Have you noticed `.attr("r", 3)` line? It sets circles' radii to be 3. If you need it to be dependent on the current node replace 3 with a function that calculates radius for current data.

Comment: Of course, I know that. I need to have a function that counts the number of links that each node has. And then I can replace 3 with that function. Writing the function is the problem that I am asking for.

Comment: Write something for me doesn't suite well into SO format. SO is Q&A site, not coding service. Voting to close.

Comment: The best way to get help is to try to implement this function on your own and ask for help with a specific problem you have ran into.

Comment: Can you include enough code to reproduce your example?  I'm really curious as to what the `graph.links.forEach` loop is doing and how you use that data later...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is bit incomplete for a concrete answer (you should show enough code to reproduce what you are doing) so here's a generalized one based of Bostock's classic [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045).  Essentially, just loop the links and count the number of times a node is linked to.  Then use this count to set the radius:

```
graph.links.forEach(function(link){

  // initialize a new property on the node
  if (!link.source["linkCount"]) link.source["linkCount"] = 0; 
  if (!link.target["linkCount"]) link.target["linkCount"] = 0;

  // count it up
  link.source["linkCount"]++;
  link.target["linkCount"]++;    
});

// use it to set radius
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
  .data(graph.nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("r", function(d){
     return d.linkCount ? (d.linkCount * 2) : 2; //<-- some function to determine radius
  });
```

Complete running [code here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NDTVwjeilYI7eZR8iKHR?p=preview).

Comment: It works well with d3.v3 however when trying the same thing with d3.v4, it seems I can't update the links dynamically.